# How do I block all settings except BlueTooth,WiFi, etc. on Soti MobiControl for Android

Tags: android, mobile, bluetooth, settings, soti

I was wondering if there is anyone out there that has experience with the Soti MobiControl MDM for Android that would be able to help me figure something out. I'm trying to block all settings except ones like BlueTooth and Wi-Fi.

I've tried using their settings manager, but this app requires me to use the lockdown screen, which I don't want to use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very late answer but:
if you don't want to use a lockdown you could try to black-list com.android.settings via app-run control in order to block access to settings and still use settings manager to let you user change settings like wifi bluetooth etc

Comment: Thank you! I tried this before I upgraded the server version and Agent version and it wouldn't work.